# How to add conditional formatting to the cell in front of the cell which content starts with certain keyword in Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, worksheet-function, excel-2019

[image: Current]

I want to extend the formatting to the next cell (which contains mins) as well. 
Here is the formula I'm using:
[image: Formula P:]
[image: Formula S:]

Both of them are applied to `=$A$1:$B$1,$36:$50,$A$2:$C$35,$E$2:$XFD$35,$D$1:$XFD$1`

Comment: i assume you mean so that it fills nicely across both cells (left of cell one is blue, and the right of cell 2 is red). I don't think that's possible, but maybe someone will find an answer

Comment: if you want to just format column c based on the values in column b, you would just add a new rule use b1 in your formula and then c:c in the applies to

Comment: Add `$` in front of `A1`: `=ISNUMBER(SEARCH("P:",$A1))`. You can than extend the range to whatever column you like to be formatted like this. The `$` locks the position of the column in the formula.

Answer (score 1):

Strictly speaking, it's not possible to distribute a gradient background across 2 cells. There are a couple of possible workarounds if you can rearrange your sheet a little:

Option 1: Concatenate the 2nd and 3rd columns into a single cell and apply formatting to that instead.

Option 2: Insert a blank column between them and make them roughly equal widths. Then create conditional formatting rules on each of the columns.

[image]

Steps for Option 2:

- Insert blank column, select the rule column and the new column, then change Horizontal Alignment to Center Across Selection:
  [image]
- Select the rule column and apply conditional formatting for a solid fill:
  [image]
- Select the minutes column and apply conditional formatting for a solid fill:
  [image]
- Select the blank column and apply conditional formatting for the gradient:
  [image]
- Repeat for the other condition

Note that when applying relative conditional formatting formulas, it is based on the Active Cell within the selection. So in my screenshots, I made each selection by click-dragging starting from the top cell down, and then referenced the first adjacent top cell in the formulas.